# What does testing if a variable is not equal to nothing do?

Tags: sas

I came across SAS code recently that looks something like this:

```
%if var_name ~= %then %do;
    flag = 1;
%end;
```

I understand that `~=` means "not equal", but there appears to be nothing here for the variable to be compared to. Can someone shed any light on this syntax?

I've ruled out the possibility that this is shorthand for identifying missing observations: the flag is generated regardless of whether `var_name` contains any missing observations. That being said, it does the exact same thing as the code that you would *think* would actually do this:

```
%if var_name ~= . %then %do;
    flag = 1;
%end;
```

The above also generates a flag with value 1 for all observations.

Any help on this greatly appreciated as I am quite new to SAS!

Comment: As written the code doesn't make sense.  `var_name ~=` is just comparing a string `"var_name"` with an empty string.  Perhaps someone left left out the `&`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is inside a data step. `var_name` is actually a variable (a float in this case).

Comment: You can't access data set variables in macro code like that.  The code is simply comparing two string literals: `"var_name"` and an empty string.  You could replace `var_name` with anything and get the same result.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see what it's doing then--in place of "var_name", which I thought was a variable name, there was actually a macro. This macro was sometimes blank, which was a way of setting an option in the program. Thanks!

Comment: Then you would have had a % in front of the var_name?

Comment: Most likely a mistake where the `&` is missing from the front of `var_name`. Look around in the code and see if there are any assignments to a macro variable called `var_name`. On a side note, allowing blank comparisons to be valid syntax was a horrible design choice by SAS.  It boggles the mind that people would then choose to  use that syntax when more readable approaches are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bestimate: The macro expression is emitting `flag=1;` as an unconditional DATA step statement .

"Coming across SAS code" can be anywhere on the continuum of a singularly rewarding experience to a journey into a deep dark place.

The snippet

```
%if var_name ~= . %then %do;
    flag = 1;
%end;
```

is construct consistent with someone who is learning macro and does not yet grok the scopes and environments within a SAS session.  Macro variables and statements do not mingle with running data step variables and statements.  Macro programming typically controls what is eventually seen as the DATA or PROC step source code that needs to be run.

There can be legitimate reasons for the snippet and therein starts your journey.

`%IF expression %THEN statement;` involves the resolution of a [macro logical expression](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1alyfc9f4qrten10sd5qz5e1w5q.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

The ***expression*** is implicitly resolved and evaluated to be zero (false) or non-zero (true).  Expressions that can not be resolved down to a non-missing numeric value at macro evaluation time will log an ERROR:

*NOTE: Macro evaluation time is long gone by the time the SAS executor has compiled and is executing the DATA Step.* [SAS Documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1gpm75owh0grun1a45z1g911dba.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) is pretty awesome, use it!.

Your `var_name ~=` expression is always true.

```
%put NOTE: %nrstr(%eval(var_name ~=)) resolves to %eval(var_name ~=);
----
NOTE: %eval(var_name ~=) resolves to 1
```

Because the %IF ***expression*** always resolves to true the %THEN ***statement*** is always resolved and emitted as source code to be consumed by the SAS executor.

So in your case the source code `flag = 1;` is emitted, ostensibly as part of a DATA step in which the flag assignment is unconditional.

Many times the ***statement*** is another macro expression that does not emit anything and instead performs an action that affects the macro state at the current macro scope -- For example `%IF &variable=&target %THEN %let target_met=1;`.

The statements around the one you noticed are really clues to whether the %IF is correct and what it should be.  What could it be?

- Does the data set be processed actually have a column named var_name ?
  Maybe you are dealing with metadata output by Proc CONTENTS, SQL DICTIONARY.COLUMNS or working in a framework that uses control data for generating statements.
- A goofup wherein the ***%if - %then*** should really be a data step ***if -then*** and the var_name should have been replaced with an actual variable name found in the data set being processed.
- Working in a code generating framework where non-empty symbols representing data step variables are used to generate data step if-then statements
- The code is the work of a madman, mad genius, or village idiot.

Happy coding!